# Produce a continuous bar on the left side of a blockquote of several paragraphs

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

I have an issue producing a continuous bar on the left side of a quotation if there are several paragraphs. If I push them together the bar becomes continuously, but the whole text isn't separated in paragraphs — one sentence follows the other without any separation or segmentation.

Example: [Meaning of . . . "I can make it up to her"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342368/meaning-of-i-can-make-it-up-to-her)

Comment: Please refer the Blockquotes option in the markdown editing help page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a `>` on the blank lines:

> “Well, and talking of Mamie?” says I.
>
> Jim paused with his trousers half on. “She's the gallantest little soul God ever made!” he cried. “Loudon, I'd meant to knock you up last night, and I hope you won't take it unfriendly that I didn't. I went in and looked at you asleep; and I saw you were all broken up, and let you be. The news would keep, anyway; and even you, Loudon, couldn't feel it the same way as I did.”
>
> “What news?” I asked.

(above text taken from [Meaning of . . . "I can make it up to her"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/342368))

This is what that looks like in pure markdown:

```
>“Well, and talking of Mamie?” says I.
>
>Jim paused with his trousers half on. “She's the gallantest little soul God ever made!” he cried. “Loudon, I'd meant to knock you up last night, and I hope you won't take it unfriendly that I didn't. I went in and looked at you asleep; and I saw you were all broken up, and let you be. The news would keep, anyway; and even you, Loudon, couldn't feel it the same way as I did.”
>
>“What news?” I asked.
```

Do note that the 'blockquote' option in the editor toolbar also achieves this but with the downside that it "reformats" long paragraphs in a broken mess with `>` interceded.